# SQL - IN vs. NOT IN

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a table with column which takes values from 1 to 10. I need to select columns with all values except for 9 and 10. Will there be a difference (performance-wise) when I use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col NOT IN (9, 10)
```

and this one?

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

Comment: `BETWEEN 1 AND 8` would likely be preferable though not worth spending any time even considering the issue for such a small table. Is your actual situation different?

Comment: sorry you right. deleting.

Comment: @Martin Smith - I was considering it as a theoretical situation, I am not going to use those queries :)

Comment: Performance will also differ largely depending on the DBMS being used. Always check the execution plan first, then you'll see.

Comment: Will there be a performance difference? Quite possibly, but which is faster would depend on which sql server you are using, how good it's optimizer is, your indexes, and how recently and how accurate it's row statistics are, and the distribution of col values.

Comment: Ah I've just noticed actually that the table itself isn't necessarily small. It just has 10 distinct values. There could be a million rows matching each value. In that case if there is a covering index with leading column `col1` I'd prefer the `BETWEEN` then the `IN`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When it comes to performance you should always profile your code (i.e. run your queries few thousand times and measure each loops performance using some kind of `stopwatch`. [Sample](http://ideone.com/WbNnJT)).

But here I highly recommend using the first query for better future maintaining. The logic is that you need all records but 9 and 10. If you add value 11 to your table and use second query, logic  of your application will be broken that will lead to bug, of course.

**Edit:** I remember this was tagged as php that's why I provided sample in php, but I might be mistaken. I guess it won't be hard to rewrite that sample in the language you're using.

Answer (score 20):

Use "IN" as it will most likely make the DBMS use an index on the corresponding column.

"NOT IN" could in theory also be translated into an index usage, but in a more complicated way which DBMS might not "spend overhead time" using.

Comment: +1 I just ran into this with SQL Server.  The `IN` version of a query only had 1% of the cost of the `NOT IN` version.  Plus, the `NOT IN` query complained of a missing index.  You'd think the optimizer would be smart enough to recognize the equivalence, but it's apparently not.  `IN` for the win!

Answer (score 3):

I have seen Oracle have trouble optimizing some queries with NOT IN if columns are nullable. If you can write your query either way, IN is preferred as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 1):

For a list of constants, MySQL will internally expand your code to:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ((col <> 9 and col <> 10))
```

Same for the other one, with 8 times `=` instead.

So yes, the first one will be faster, less comparisons to be done. Chances that it is measurable are negligible though, the overhead of a handful of constant comparisons is nothing compared to the general overhead of parsing SQL and retrieving data.

Comment: The OP hasn't told us what RDBMS they are on but AFAIK in MySQL an `IN` with a list of constants is implemented using binary search of the list rather than 8 `=` comparisons.

Comment: Even if it did (I never count on MySQL to do any kind of 'advanced' optimization, safest assumption) it makes the second one theoretically slightly slower because there's still more comparisons to be done.

Answer (score -1):

"IN" statement works internally like a serie of "OR" statements.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Its equals to

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col = 1 OR col = 2 OR col = 3
```

"OR" statements could cause some performance issues as explained in this article:
https://bertwagner.com/2018/02/20/or-vs-union-all-is-one-better-for-performance/

When you do a NOT IN statement, its all the same, but the result has a logical denial. BUT, you could write and equivalent query much better in performance. In your example:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col NOT IN (9, 10)
```

Its equals to

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col <> 9 AND col <> 10
```

With an "AND" statement, the database stop analizing when one of all conditionals its false, so, its much better in performance than "OR" used in "IN" statement.

Comment: this argument is invalid because it goes both ways: `AND` chains have to continue if the previous term returns `true`, `OR` chains it will stop immediately