# Why would an NOT IN condition be slower than IN in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I was asked this question few days back, in a interview. What is the reason for this slowness?

Comment: I don't see any reason why... it depends on the data and on the query.. also a IN condition could be slower... it seems a tricky question:maybe if the NOT IN condition has more items then the IN condition

Comment: Is this with a constant list or with a subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in), `in` with a list of constants implements a binary search:

> The search for the item then is done using a binary search. This
>   means IN is very quick if the IN value list consists entirely of
>   constants.

It is *not explicitly* stated that `NOT IN` is handled the same way, but it is reasonable to assume based on this:

> - expr NOT IN (value,...)
>
> This is the same as NOT (expr IN (value,...)).

That would leave two possible differences in performance.  The first would be index usage.  Because `NOT IN` is documented as essentially using `IN`, I would expect the index optimizations to be the same.  This is an expectation, but it might not be correct.

The second is that there are fewer comparisons with the `NOT IN` than with the `IN`.  This would lead to the `NOT IN` being faster -- but the difference is less than microscopic given the binary search method used by MySQL.  In other words, this should not make a difference.

Finally, if you are using a subquery, then all bets are off.  The `NOT IN` has to process the entire list to check if the value is not really in the list.  `IN` can stop processing at the first match.  Under some circumstances, this could have an impact on performance.

Answer (score 2):

It is up to your data.

And i found an another answer for you :

> Use "IN" as it will most likely make the DBMS use an index on the
>   corresponding column.
>
> "NOT IN" could in theory also be translated into an index usage, but
>   in a more complicated way which DBMS might not "spend overhead time"
>   using.

From : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16892027/3444315

Answer (score 1):

It's because `NOT IN` is simply `NOT (IN)`. It's always one more step than `IN`. `NOT IN` take the result of `IN` then negates it.