# NOT IN query takes too long to respond

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I am having a table with around 20000 records. I am running this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.ci_record_id FROM `ip_connection` t WHERE
  t.remote_ip NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.ipAddress FROM ci_table t1 WHERE 
          t1.blueprint_id IN (SELECT t2.id FROM blueprints t2 WHERE t2.ci_part=FALSE) 
      AND t1.archive=FALSE
  );
```

Same query if I run with **IN** clause it will run within seconds and will return 18000 records. **NOT IN** query just hangs the system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - IN vs. NOT IN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891668/sql-in-vs-not-in)

Comment: Actually I just mentioned IN query works fine with so much of records. I need the result with NOT IN itself. I am expecting an optimised query for the same results

Comment: It's always good, when asking performance questions, to include table definitions with indexes,and to include the output of `EXPLAIN`. Without those things we must assume stuff, which makes an ass out of "u" and me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use the `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` pattern to give this a boost.  Here's something to try.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.ci_record_id 
  FROM ip_connection t
  LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT DISTINCT t1.ipAddress 
           FROM ci_table t1 
           JOIN blueprints t2    ON t1.blueprint_id = t2.i2
                                AND t2.ci_part=FALSE
          WHERE t1.archive = FALSE
        ) ta ON t.remote_ip = ta.ipAddress
  WHERE ta.ipAddress IS NULL
```

What I've done here is factored out your dependent subquery (the one in your `NOT IN`) clause and made it into an independent subquery, like so.

```
         SELECT DISTINCT t1.ipAddress 
           FROM ci_table t1 
           JOIN blueprints t2    ON t1.blueprint_id = t2.i2
                                AND t2.ci_part=FALSE
          WHERE t1.archive = FALSE
```

You should be able to test this subquery independently. It should yield the list of unarchived t1 items corresponding to the list of unarchived blueprint items.

Then, I `LEFT JOIN`ed it to your toplevel table, then I looked for NULL items on the right side of the join. Those NULL items correspond to rows on the left side of the join that didn't match the ON clause.  That's the independent subquery way of doing `NOT IN`.

This is likely to help you, because MySQL's query planner is a little bit naive about dependent subqueries and sometimes repeats them until the sun becomes a white dwarf star.

Comment: It works. Can you help me to get the asset_name from ci_table where record_id is the result of this query and again it is not archived and not a ci_part

Comment: Have you tried using `SELECT DISTINCT t.ci_record_id, t.asset_name` in the first line of your query?  I don't know your table layout so I can't help much.

Comment: asset_name  is a column in ci_table . ci_record_id is a column in ip_connection table. After getting the ci_record_id  from ip_connection  table I want to get the asset_name for all those in ci_table